# cascade constraints in Oracle

Tags: oracle, constraint, cascade

Can we use the cascade constraints instead of specifying FK in our code

I mean can we Use this

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE @PCWSCHEMA@pcwscannermaster DROP CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
```

instead of the below

```
execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE @PCWSCHEMA@pcwscannermaster DROP CONSTRAINT pcwscannermaster_id_pk';
```

Thanks for your swift response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

```
drop table t3 purge;
drop table t2 purge;
drop table t1 purge;

create table t1 (t1_id number not null, constraint t1_pk primary key (t1_id));
create table t2 (t1_id number not null, 
  constraint t2_t1_fk foreign key(t1_id) references t1(t1_id));
create table t3 (t1_id number not null, 
  constraint t3_t1_fk foreign key(t1_id) references t1(t1_id));

SQL> select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, r_constraint_name
     from user_constraints where table_name in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3') order by 1, 3

TABLE_NAME CONSTRAINT_NAME      C R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
---------- -------------------- - --------------------
T1         SYS_C005936          C
T1         T1_PK                P
T2         SYS_C005938          C
T2         T2_T1_FK             R T1_PK
T3         SYS_C005940          C
T3         T3_T1_FK             R T1_PK

6 rows selected.

SQL> alter table t1 drop constraint t1_pk cascade;

Table altered.

SQL> select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type, r_constraint_name
     from user_constraints where table_name in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3') order by 1, 3;

TABLE_NAME CONSTRAINT_NAME      C R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
---------- -------------------- - --------------------
T1         SYS_C005936          C
T2         SYS_C005938          C
T3         SYS_C005940          C
```